# Facing issues while Migrating application from Websphere 7.0 to Websphere 8.5.5

Tags: java, struts2, migration, websphere-8, websphere-7

The application is developed in Struts 2 and working fine in Websphere 7.0.

Now I am deploying in Websphere 8.5.5. It is giving login page and I am able to login into application but on clicking of any menu, It is giving the below exception.

```
Jars used are - aopalliance-1.0.jar, axis.jar, c3p0-0.9.1.1.jar, com.springsource.javax.transaction-1.1.0.jar, commons-beanutils-1.8.3.jar, commons-beanutils-bean-collections-1.8.3.jar, commons-beanutils-core-1.8.3.jar, commons-collections-3.2.1.jar, commons-io-1.3.2.jar, commons-lang-2.6.jar, commons-logging-1.1.1.jar, commons-logging-adapters-1.1.1.jar, commons-logging-api-1.1.1.jar, commons-logging-tests.jar, commons-logging.jar, datamodel-1.0.jar, displaytag-1.2.jar, dsn.jar, freemarker-2.3.13.jar, jsp-api.jar, jstl-1.2.jar, jstl-standard.jar, log4j-1.2.16.jar, ognl-2.7.3.jar, ojdbc6.jar, poi-3.8-20120326.jar, servlet-api.jar, spring-2.5.6.jar, spring-beans-2.5.6.jar, spring-context-2.5.6.jar, spring-core-2.5.6.jar, struts2-convention-plugin-2.1.6.jar, struts2-core-2.1.6.jar, struts2-dojo-plugin-2.1.6.jar, struts2-jquery-plugin-1.4.jar, struts2-spring-plugin-2.1.8.jar, struts2-tiles-plugin-2.1.6.jar, tiles-api-2.1.2.jar, tiles-compat-2.1.2.jar, tiles-core-2.1.2.jar, tiles-jsp-2.1.2.jar, tiles-portlet-2.1.2.jar, tiles-servlet-2.1.2.jar 



 [2/28/16 12:56:36:880 AST] 000000c1 servlet       I com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper init SRVE0242I: [E-Manager] [/eManager] [/jsps/tiles/baseLayout.jsp]: Initialization successful.
    [2/28/16 12:56:37:005 AST] 000000c1 servlet       I com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper init SRVE0242I: [E-Manager] [/eManager] [/jsps/tiles/menu.jsp]: Initialization successful.
    [2/28/16 12:56:37:130 AST] 000000c1 servlet       I com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper init SRVE0242I: [E-Manager] [/eManager] [/jsps/welcome.jsp]: Initialization successful.
    [2/28/16 12:56:40:646 AST] 000000c1 ExceptionMapp E com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger error null
                                     java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:440)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:279)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
        at com.shb.emanager.interceptor.LoginInterceptor.intercept(LoginInterceptor.java:97)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:163)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:249)
        at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:122)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:195)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:195)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:148)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
        at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:93)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
        at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:235)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:89)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:128)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
        at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ProfilingActivationInterceptor.intercept(ProfilingActivationInterceptor.java:104)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
        at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:267)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:126)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:138)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:148)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
        at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:128)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:176)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
        at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:52)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:468)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:76)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:192)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:89)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:96)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:192)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:89)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:926)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1023)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3703)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:304)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:962)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:195)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:458)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:522)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:311)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:87)
        at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
        at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
        at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
        at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
        at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
        at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
        at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
        at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1783)
```

Comment: adding a description for the question is the right way to do it.

Comment: The application is developed in struts2 and working fine in websphere 7.0. Now i am deploying in websphere 8.5.5. It is giving login page and i am able to login into application but on clicking of any menu, It is giving the above exception. Please help.

Comment: Please add necessary details to the question, without them it seems impossible to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use new version of websphere without updating these libraries. The best for you is to let Maven to do it.

See [Create Struts 2 Web Application Using Maven To Manage Artifacts and To Build The Application](https://struts.apache.org/getting-started/how-to-create-a-struts2-web-application.html).

> Maven is a powerful, extendable, open source project builder. The configuration is contained in the XML files, so it's easily accessible by the any text editor. If you want to share the configuration what you will do is just post the `pom.xml`. Many IDEs have converters of the project configuration to Eclipse and from Eclipse but this configuration is local and used internally by the development environment. Developers even not save such configuration in the VCS. Checking out such configuration has no sense. But maven is independent because it relies on external repositories that keep track of every library and version used by the project. Many IDEs including Eclipse have Maven support via plugins. That can keep intact both configurations.

> The `pom.xml` for core struts2 application requires only
>
> ```xml
> <dependency>
>     <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
>     <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
>     <version>X.X.X.X</version>
> </dependency>
> ```
>
> and it will download all other dependencies. Integrating with other
>   frameworks use plugins and don't mess up dependencies that are
>   duplicated.

Comment: @ Roman......... this thing i already did and this is working fine with websphere 7.0 and when i am trying the same on Websphere 8.5.5 it is giving the exception which i have shown.

Comment: No, you didn't. The file you posted is *struts2-core-2.1.6.jar*.

Comment: The latest stable version is Struts 2.3.24.1.